# Bottom padding of FAB gone when Snackbar appears

Tags: android, floating-action-button, android-snackbar

Moin,

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour with a FAB inside a `CoordinatorLayout`.
When a `Snackbar` appears, the FAB slides up, but sticks directly to the `Snackbar` without any `padding` (second image).
After the `Snackbar` is gone, the FAB moves down to the edge of the screen with no padding (third image) until a few seconds later, when the FAB magically moves up again (layout revalidate?) and the padding is back to normal (fourth image).

I've tested this from API 16 to 23.

[image: step1]

[image: step2]

[image: step3]

[image: step4]

My layout looks like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/pullToRefreshContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/empty"
            [...]
        </LinearLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabAdd"
            style="@style/MyTheme.FloatingActionButton"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/recycler"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
            app:useCompatPadding="true"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

The according theme looks like this:

```
<style name="MyTheme.FloatingActionButton" parent="Widget.Design.FloatingActionButton">
    <item name="android:layout_width">56dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">56dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">bottom|right</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:scaleType">center</item>
</style>
```

Does anyone have a clue what causes this behavior?
I want the FAB to preserve its `padding` all the time.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered recently the very same problem. TL;DR; I solved it by:

```
public class MyFabBehavior extends FloatingActionButton.Behavior {
    public MyFabBehavior() {
        super();
    }

    public MyFabBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean getInsetDodgeRect(
            @NonNull CoordinatorLayout parent,
            @NonNull FloatingActionButton child,
            @NonNull Rect rect) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Explanation:

`CoordinatorLayout` allows its children to set `dodgeInsetEdges`. Its a gravity value. Without this parameter whenever another child moves into our view's rectangle, they overlap. However, with `dodgeInsetEdges` set CoordinatorLayout will move our view to avoid overlapping from the specified direction. Default value for FAB is bottom.

Moreover CoordinatorLayout allows us, instead of using the view's rectangle to define our own. This can be done by overriding `getInsetDodgeRect` in our behavior. FAB does that, and there is where the problem starts.

On pre-Lollipop devices or when `useCompatPadding` is set to true, FAB will have added padding used to draw its shadow. It is necessary as on pre-Lollipop views cannot draw the shadow outside their bounds.

According to the comments in FAB's default behavior, after adding the shadow padding, FAB should offset itself back to its original position. This is however not happening. On the other hand dodge inset rect is still offset and therefore the FAB is pushed up after Snackbar covers the shadow and then dragged all the way to the bottom. The solution above basically reverts it to default.

At this point I still don't know why the offsetting of FAB doesn't work as expected. Maybe if somebody can provide more info about that, better solution could be found.